# Creating a List by combining two lists

Tags: c#

I am new to .Net. I have two objects, `Customer` and `Country` in my project :

```
public class Customer
{
  public int CustomerId {get;set;}
  public string CustomerName {get;set}
  public String Street {get;set}
  public String Address {get;set}
  public int CountryId {get;set}
  //...o
}


public class Country
{
  public int CountryId {get;set;}
  public String CountryName{get;set}
}
```

I have two lists, `List<Customer>` and `List<Country>.`

I am using a sql join statement to list customers with country. But I am confused how can I create a single list which contains customers along with the country name.

Is it necessary to create separate class for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of storing country id in your Customer class, just store the object itself. That is, make it like this:

```
public Class Customer
{
public int CustomerId {get;set;}
public string CustomerName {get;set}
public String Street {get;set}
public String Address {get;set}
public Country Country {get;set}
//...o
}
```

Then you have all the needed info in your `Customer` object, and there's no need to try to merge lists or anything like that.

On your `SQL` statement, join to country table and get the country name as part of the result set, then you can populate the customer list in one server round trip.

Answer (score 1):

You could add to your customer class

```
public Country country { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can do get the data in the correct format from the database, by all means, do so first! The data is optimized for that.

But if you have two lists and you need to work with that, LINQ should help. You can do something like this:

```
var query = from customer in customers
            from country in countries
            where customer.CountryId == country.CountryId
            select new
            {
                Customer = customer,
                Country = country
            };
```

This will give a collection of anonymous objects with a `Customer` property holding a customer and a `Country` property holding the matching country.

If you really need to work with the type `List<>` you can always write `query.ToList()`.

If anonymous types are not your thing, you can either create a new class or maybe improve the `Customer` class to reference a `Country` and return an instance of that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to either create a class that contains separate properties for each (Customer and Country), or, you need to create an enhanced customer class that contains an additional Country property.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx).

It is Microsoft's Object-Relational-Mapper (ORM) and it is designed for abstracting database access just like you're trying to do.